# JSON answer to check if a server is reachable

Tags: iphone, ios, json, reachability

I have an app that just opened call a webserver page that gives me a json string.
When I'm on the local network all works without problem but when I open the app outside the local network and without vpn the app crashes.
How can I control the json string?
This is my code:

```
NSString *urlstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@yes.php", av];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlstr];

NSError* error = nil;
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
NSString *newStr;

NSData* data=[newStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 

                                                     options:kNilOptions 
                                                       error:&error];

sn1 = [[json objectForKey:@"Rele1"] intValue];
```

I want to compare the json answer with a NULL value, if the two parameters are equal I show an alert.

**EDIT: If I try to read any value, the app crashes waiting the json reply...
I have bypassed the problem with an NSURLRequest with the timeoutInterval parameter that closes the connection after n seconds.**

Comment: You have an `error:&error` parameter, but you never check it after the call. I have absolutely no experience with the API you're using, but I'll bet anything that the results are unusable when an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Amongst other things, you fail to:

- check whether the attempt to fetch an ASCII-encoded string from a remote URL failed (obvious possibilities: the URL is unreachable, the result is UTF-8 rather than ASCII);
- check whether the JSON parsing succeeds (obvious possibility: the server 404d and returned an HTML error page instead)
- check whether the returned JSON object was actually a dictionary (eg, it could be an array, in which case calling `objectForKey:` on it will raise an exception)

The parsing of return data as ASCII then re-encoding into UTF-8 is also probably redundant — because the one supersets the other it has the effect of a threshold test, otherwise preventing acceptable results from proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Does this code ever worked?

1. You should check `error` after `[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];`
2. you are reading URL data into `urlString` but then get NSData from uninitialized `newStr` and parse it?
3. again you should always check `error` whenever you provide it before anything else
4. why do you read the data as ASCII but the NSData as UTF8?